# Unable to lookup: java:/TransactionManager - Unable to instantiate legacy transaction manager

Tags: spring, jboss, transactionmanager

i have a problem when i start in debug my application server (JBoss EAP 6.1).
When it start, in console i have this information in DEBUG:

```
15:50:46,530 DEBUG [org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to lookup: java:/TransactionManager: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up TransactionManager, service service jboss.naming.context.java.TransactionManager is not started
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:132) [jboss-as-naming-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:80) [jboss-as-naming-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:197) [jboss-as-naming-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:120) [jboss-as-naming-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:183) [jboss-as-naming-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:179) [jboss-as-naming-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator.tryJNDI(TransactionManagerLocator.java:150) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator.locate(TransactionManagerLocator.java:131) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator.locateTransactionManager(TransactionManagerLocator.java:94) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:93) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:60) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.txn.service.ArjunaTransactionManagerService.start(ArjunaTransactionManagerService.java:103) [jboss-as-transactions-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]

15:50:46,530 DEBUG [org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator] (MSC service thread 1-7) Unable to instantiate legacy transaction manager: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.tm.TxManager from [Module "org.jboss.jboss-transaction-spi:main" from local module loader @598ef578 (finder: local module finder @3895c737 (roots: C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.0\jboss-eap-6.1\modules,C:\Program Files\EAP-6.1.0\jboss-eap-6.1\modules\system\layers\base))]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:196) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:444) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:374) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:119) [jboss-modules.jar:1.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator.usePrivateAPI(TransactionManagerLocator.java:172) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator.locate(TransactionManagerLocator.java:133) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.TransactionManagerLocator.locateTransactionManager(TransactionManagerLocator.java:94) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:93) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction.(ServerVMClientUserTransaction.java:60) [jboss-transaction-spi-7.0.0.Final-redhat-2.jar:7.0.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.txn.service.ArjunaTransactionManagerService.start(ArjunaTransactionManagerService.java:103) [jboss-as-transactions-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
```

Also if it's in DEBUG, i would understand the problem, because i don't know where is the problem. Any suggetsion?